# How to pass an input from a UITextField to a UILabel in different controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

Basically I have a table view cell that is set up with two UILabels, one on left and one on the right. The first one on the left is titled Bus Name and will remain static.  The one on the right will change based on the what the user inputs on the textfield in another view controller.  I have a modal segue set up such that when a user clicks on the cell, they are directed to the view controller with a textfield.  The text within that field should then be updated on the UILabel on the previous table view cell when the user taps Done in the navigation. What is the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use custom delegate to done this... Which is more better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your prepareForSegue method, store a weak reference to the sender (which will be your UITableViewCell) on your modal view controller.  Assuming you have the UILabel exposed on your UITableViewCell you'll be able to set it directly.  For example:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;
    UIViewController* controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.callingCell = cell;
}
```

Assuming on your modal view you have the following property:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UITableViewCell* callingCell;
```

You can then say:

```
self.callingCell.desiredTextField.text = @"Text";
```

Instead of keeping a reference to the UITableViewCell itself, you could also create a protocol that only exposes the ability to set the text field you desire. Then your UITableViewCell would conform to that.  For example:

```
@protocol SettableLabel <NSObject>

-(void) setText:(NSString*) text;

@end
```

Then your UITableViewCell would conform to that protocol and have the method implemented:

```
-(void) setText:(NSString*) text {
    self.desiredTextField.text = text;
}
```

Then on your modal view you'd have the property:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<SettableLabel>* callingCell;
```

and would just call setText when you need to. This may be a better design but I leave that decision to you.

Comment: I have two UILabels within that one UITableViewCell. Is there a way to differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have few options but the most simple, common way is to use delegation.

In the controller with the text field you should declare a Delegate Protocol.

```
@protocol YourTextFieldViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)userDidFinishEditingWithText:(NSString *)text;
@end

@interface YourTextFieldViewController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,weak) id < YourTextFieldViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then when the user taps done or any other trigger that you want to set, in your YourTextFieldViewController call -

```
[self.delegate userDidFinishEditingWithText:yourTextField.text];
```

Now what you basically did is to create a way for you YourTextFieldViewController to announce the "world" that your text field text is done editing.  When your YourTextFieldViewController calls the delegate method it "shouts" - "Hey, if there is any one interested in this text, here is it".

But for it to work someone needs to say, "Hey, I want to get this message when from the YourTextFieldViewController. For that your TableviewController will say to the YourTextFieldViewController - "I want to be your delegate, and get your messages". (This is different from Notifications where any one can get them even if it does not know the sender, In the delegate pattern, you must "Know" the sender).

So to do that your TableviewController register itself as the delegate of the YourTextFieldViewController -

In the header file you need to declare that you are implementing the YourTextFieldViewControllerDelegate delegate:

```
@interface YourTableViewController : UIViewController<YourTextFieldViewControllerDelegate >

@end
```

Then you need to tell YourTextFieldViewController that you want to be it's delegate:

```
YourTextFieldViewController *controller =  [[YourTextFieldViewController alloc] init];
controller.delegate = self;
```

And lastly, implement the delegate method -

```
 - (void)userDidFinishEditingWithText:(NSString *)text
 {
       //here you should update your table view dataSource array
 }
```

BTW you are already using delegate method if you are using UITableView.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding ,

class A has tableview and on the selection of table cell opening some modal view.
In modal view user is entering some data which is passing to class A table cell label.

So my solution for this, create one protocol in modal view and call delegate for updated changes in class A table.